# ERROR: Could not detect Ninja v1.7 or newer (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apt, software-installation, qemu

While trying to install qemu-5.2.0, I found the build method has changed to mesa.(I don't know why they change things sometimes to make our lives difficult... :) )
Under build directory, I did `../configure --target-list=aarch64-softmmu --enable-debug` as usual, and it gave me at the last line

```
ERROR: Could not detect Ninja v1.7 or newer
```

I tried installing ninja by `sudo apt-get install ninja` and in removed old version and re-installed ninja. But as you can see, the installed ninja version is too low. (it expects 1.7 or newer)

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep ninja
ii  ninja                                                       0.1.3-2                                                     amd64        Privilege escalation detection system for GNU/Linux
rc  ninja-build                                                 1.5.1-0.1ubuntu1                                            amd64        small build system closest in spirit to Make
```

What is the best way to install Ninja 1.7 or newer? (I'm on ubuntu 16.04)

ADD :
I found you can install ninja 1.7 on ubuntu 16.05 : git clone github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git, then cd ninja; git checkout v1.7.0; ./configure --bootstrap. now ninja is built on that local directory. you link to previous ninja executable like /usr/bin/ninja. this works ok. (but as others said, upgrading to higher version of ubuntu might be better)

Comment: Just to remind you 16.04 is EOL in April so no more support or updates after that time. Might be a good time to upgrade. It may also help with your issue.

Comment: @David Ah, thanks for the info.

Comment: ninja 1.7 is in `xenial-backports`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/ninja-build. By the way, the package is `ninja-build`. [`ninja`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ninja) is something else.

Comment: @muru hi, thanks! didn't know that. :)

Comment: @muru but I want to leave my question here, because people cannot find the answer in the 'duplicate question link' by this ninja version problem. How can they go to the solution when they don't know it's coming from old ubuntu version?

Comment: @ChanKim no worries, duplicate questions aren't deleted automatically. One look at the comments and any incoming users will see the duplicates provide the actual instructions for getting their relevant package.

Comment: I found you can install ninja 1.7 on ubuntu 16.05 : git clone https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git, then  cd ninja; git checkout v1.7.0; ./configure --bootstrap. now ninja is built on that local directory. you link to previous ninja executable like /usr/bin/ninja. this works ok. (but as others said, upgrading to higher version of ubuntu might be better)